# Apparition hangs after "DevTools listening on"

Tags: capybara, apparition

macos 10.13.6
jruby 9.2.0.0
rspec 3.8.2
capybara 3.28.0
apparition 0.3.0
chrome 76.0.3809.100

Current configuration (tried various options that had no effect:

```rb
require 'capybara/apparition'

Capybara.register_driver :apparition do |app|
  Capybara::Apparition::Driver.new(app, { headless: true })
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_max_wait_time = 10
  config.ignore_hidden_elements = true
  config.default_driver = :apparition
  config.javascript_driver = :apparition
end
```

I'm getting something like this when I attempt to run using apparition:

```
Capybara starting Puma...
* Version 4.1.0 , codename: Fourth and One
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:50136

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50140/devtools/browser/003bf437-48ff-45f9-ac9e-fa0526d904dc
```

After which it sits there until I force quit out. If headless mode is off, it pops open a browser window, which I can use to visit the Puma listening port but otherwise doesn't actually do anything.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Disclaimer: The reason I tried this in the first place was that chrome/chromedriver updated and borked my selenium chromedriver setup.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: This should be fixed in Apparition 0.4.0

——————————————-

Apparition currently isn't working with JRuby - you'll have to swap to MRI to test using Capybara with Apparition.